# Date / time out of sync by days

Tags: windows-server-2003, time, synchronization, date

I have several 2003 servers in my domain that randomly change their date/time by several days, sometimes. They are all getting their time from an AD server acting as the primary DC.

I have looked in the event viewer to find that in the evening the time just jumps from around 7pm (correct date) to 10am (several days ahead).

to re-sync, I have been issuing the command "net time /domain /set /y" however its not ideal as the server should be functioning before I have chance to issue the command.

Comment: Have you checked that the timezone is correct on these servers?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Sam said, also check the command `net time /querysntp` on the server's that it's doing that on. That should tell you the server name that your misguided server is getting the time from. If that isn't correct  you can use

```
net time /setsntp:"mylocalserver"
net stop w32time
net start w32time
w32tm /resync /rediscover
```

Comment: The time-zones are all correct, when querying the servers they tell me that they are getting their time from time.windows.com,0x1

when I enter 'net time' it says current time at the backup AD server
however when i type net time /domain /set it asks if im sure i want to sync to the correct AD server, which is also confusing

Comment: net time will tell you the time from the which ever domain controler the server is currently talking to (there's no such thing as a backup DC). I believe by running the command net time /domain /set you are setting the time based on the current domain controler. I don't believe that will set your sntp server to that for the next polling period, you can confirm that by doing net time /querysntp again after you set that. I would check the event log the next time this issue happens, computers will log all sntp events in the system event log.

Comment: We have two AD servers on site, one used as a backup and another in use,  when I issue 'net time' it refers to the backup AD however when i issue 'net time /domain /set' it refers to the PDC in use.

in the event log all is fine until 19.55 then the next event jumps 6 days ahead and 3 hours later, the only correspondence of w32time says make sure the time and timezone are correct at the timesource (active AD box)

Comment: also when i querysntp on the affected box, the current value is time.windows.com - should this not be the AD box?